# Windows 10 Toast Notification with scenario set to "incomingCall" messes up the notification UI

Tags: node.js, notifications, electron, toast, windows-10-desktop

I am working on an Electron app which uses NodeRT to show toast notifications in Windows 10. So far, I have got things working and a "ToastGeneric" notification shows up fine.

The app is expected to show a notification to the user when the app gets an incoming call.

A regular toast shows up fine:

[image: Regular Toast]

However, if I add a `scenario="incomingCall"` to the `<toast>`, it messes up the UI.

[image: Toast as incomingCall]

I could not find any proper documentation on this behavior anywhere. I even tried using a [code sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/Notifications/cs/Notifications/ScenarioPages/Toasts/Scenarios/IncomingCall/ScenarioElement.xaml.cs) given by Microsoft, but that does not work either.

Any idea where is this going wrong?

Here is my toast payload:

```xml
<toast>
    <visual>
        <binding template='ToastGeneric'>
            <text>%s</text>
            <text>%s, %s</text>
            <group>
            <subgroup>
                <text hint-style="base">52 attendees</text>
                <text hint-style="captionSubtle">23 minute drive</text>
            </subgroup>
            <subgroup>
                <text hint-style="captionSubtle" hint-align="right">1 Microsoft Way</text>
                <text hint-style="captionSubtle" hint-align="right">Bellevue, WA 98008</text>
            </subgroup>
            </group>
        </binding>
    </visual>
    <actions>
        <action arguments = 'answer'
                content = 'answer' />
        <action arguments = 'ignore'
                content = 'ignore' />
    </actions>
</toast>
```

Comment: I'm not familar with electron but as the official sample also not work this might be a issue that need to be tracked. Can you share me your OS version and target SDK version?

Comment: Also can you show me a image to show how is the official sample showing?

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT, the buttons in the official sample appear exactly like as shown in the screenshot above. If I leave just one `action` it appears like the "Ignore" button in the second screenshot.

Comment: Windows version: 10.0.17134.0. I am really not sure how to get the SDK version. I am not a Windows developer. I have VS 2015 and VS 2017, both installed. VS2017 shows the SDK version 10.0.17763.0. Not sure about VS2015 though. I set my paths like so: `$env:VCTargetsPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\v140"` and `$env:path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\amd64;" + $env:path`, if that helps in anyway.

Comment: Based on your Toast template, we tested it in the 18362 system and it works fine.

I noticed that you used **NodeRT** to call the Windows Runtime APIs. Based on this, I offer two suggestions.

1. You can create a new UWP app and use the standard `ToastNotificationManager` to test the notification to see if it is normal.
2. If the former performs normally, this indicates that **NodeRT** has a problem during the push notification. It is recommended that you initiate an issue to the provider of the package.

I will also test in the 17134 system to see the performance of the notification.

Comment: @Richasy, thank you for your help. I will try out `ToastNotificationManager`. Would you happen to have any sample code that I can use? Like I said, I am not a Windows developer, so a working code will be really helpful.

Comment: @funkycoder Hi, don't worry. You don't have to write code, you can download **Notifications Visualizer** directly in the Microsoft Store, enter your toast template and see the display. If the UI is different, the problem may not be on the system version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the suggestion provided by @Richard Zhang, I tried out the template in Notifications Visualizer.

It produced the same messed up UI that I see happening through NodeRT. It seems that the `incomingCall` scenario mandatorily requires the template to provide the two (or three, I don't remember exactly) buttons right after the body. And then a final row with Answer and Decline button.

It would have been really cool to be able to use that scenario, however, I had to go with the regular toast notification.